# In Node.js Html and Static files css, js. The result is "Waiting for localhost" loading

Tags: html, node.js

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

if(req.url.indexOf('.html') != -1){ //req.url has the pathname, check if it conatins '.html'

  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html', function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
  });

}

if(req.url.indexOf('.js') != -1){ //req.url has the pathname, check if it conatins '.js'

  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/public/js/material.js', function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/javascript'});
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
  });

}

if(req.url.indexOf('.css') != -1){ //req.url has the pathname, check if it conatins '.css'

  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/public/css/material.css', function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/css'});
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
  });

}

}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Comment: Would you edit this to include a specific problem statement and the question you have? It is not clear what you are asking at present.

Comment: I want to access static file in Node js without Any 3rd Party Modules??

Comment: How did you get on with the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't enough information here to say what is failing, but here are some options that should help you to troubleshoot.

Check the network tab to see what file/s are failing to load.

[image: network tab]

Add some console.log statements to see which code is actually running. This will narrow down what is failing.

I'd like to point out that your routing logic is pretty strange. You are only checking the extension of a file and serving the same file for every request of that type. For example, if I request /literally/any/path/to/some.js, it will always respond with material.js. I'm guessing you will want to load more js files in the future.

I recommend using a framework like [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express). It will let you easily serve a static file directory.

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

This will allow you to load any file in public as a static file.

- /js/material.js -> serves public/js/material.js
- /css/material.css -> serves public/css/material.css